# How to prevent a USB 3g modem from changing current interface

Tags: raspbian, networking

I setup a Raspbx installation on a Raspberry 3 but i'm having a strange problem.

I connected the RP to wifi by default, and set up my /etc/network/interfaces like this:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
wpa-ssid "MyWifiRouter"
wpa-psk "XXXXX"
address 192.168.0.77
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-search google.com
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

It all works fine, but whenever I plug a 3g modem (huawei) into the RP it completely disconnects it and my SSH session over wifi to the RP gets frozen (timed out).

This goes on maybe for 5 minutes or as soon as i disconnects the 3g dongle i can instantly log back in.

I checked `/var/log/messages` to see if the modem messes with my current interface and i found this:

```
...
...
May 19 00:15:10 raspbx kernel: [    5.571517] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    5.694510] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    5.694540] brcmfmac: power management disabled
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    5.703281] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1520
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    5.703299] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    5.703308] usb 1-1.3: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    5.703316] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    5.706479] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    5.709479] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    6.039563] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
May 19 00:15:11 raspbx kernel: [    6.077969] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
May 19 00:15:14 raspbx kernel: [    9.029424] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
May 19 00:15:16 raspbx kernel: [   11.510456] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
May 19 00:15:16 raspbx kernel: [   11.510579] NET: Registered protocol family 31
May 19 00:15:16 raspbx kernel: [   11.510591] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
...
...
```

I'm not sure what to make of this, but I see:
`usbcore: registered new interface driver uas`

And i think it maybe does change the interface and kicks me out, I'm not interested in the internet capabilities of the modem, i'm just using it for GSM calls through the pbx setup.

Answer (score 0):

You are using obsolete networking settings!

One of the problems with Debian networking is that it does not handle multiple interfaces well.

Restore default Raspbian networking (using `dhcpcd`) as described in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

This supports simultaneous connection over many interfaces, although you may need to customise to ensure there is only 1 default route. The tutorial describes how to set an interface to nogateway.

Comment: Thanks Milliways, althought this didn't help with the freezing at all